# How to change the image on a grid layout once you click on it?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

I am trying to make a 3x3 grid layout of images(ImageView), and once the user click on any of the images the photo on that image changes, the problem I'm facing here is that I can not find a reference to the image that is being clicked so that I can change the photo on it. The game I am trying to write is a simple tic tac toe
1) Here is the code for my main Activity

```
package eg.edu.guc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.GridView;
//import android.widget.Toast

public class AndXOActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        // Instance of ImageAdapter Class
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Toast.makeText(AndXOActivity.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //ImageView imageView = new ImageView(getMContext());
                getImageView().setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

2) Here is the code for the ImageAdapter class

```
import android.content.Context;  
import android.database.DataSetObserver;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

       private Context mContext;
       public ImageView imageView;

       public ImageView getImageView() {
        return imageView;
    }

        // Keep all Images in array
        public Integer[] mThumbIds = {
                R.drawable.sample_0, R.drawable.sample_1,
                R.drawable.sample_2, R.drawable.sample_3,
                R.drawable.sample_4, R.drawable.sample_5,
                R.drawable.sample_6, R.drawable.sample_7,
                R.drawable.x, R.drawable.o

        };

        // Constructor
        public ImageAdapter(Context c){
            mContext = c;
        }
        public Context getMContext() {
            return mContext;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mThumbIds.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return mThumbIds[position];
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.tile);
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(70, 70));
            return imageView;
        }
    }
```

3) Here is the .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/gridview"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:numColumns="3"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:gravity="center"
/>
```

Please tell me what should I do to make the image change once I click on the ImageView!

Answer (score 0):

1. Loop over the ImageViews themselves, give them all the same OnClickListener, but also tag them with an index into that array of images that you have.  In the listener, get the tag, index into the array, do what you need to do now that you know the image associated with the ImageView, change the tag.

An example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
  super.onCreate(bundle);
  setContentView(R.layout.select);
  OnClickListener listener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent i = new Intent(SelectActivity.this, QuizActivity.class);
      i.putExtra("quiz#", ((Integer) v.getTag()).intValue());  // <------
      i.putExtra("mode", ((RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.modeSelect)).getCheckedRadioButtonId());
      startActivity(i);
    }
  };

  int index = 0;
  for (int quiz: Quizzes.quizzes) {
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(quiz);
    b.setOnClickListener(listener);
    b.setTag(Integer.valueOf(index++)); // <------
  }
}
```

2. Forget this GridView of ImageViews.  Instead, subclass View and draw the tic-tac-toe board yourself, and have your board respond to clicks.  After the board calculates the quadrant clicked, it can refer to its own internal model of the game to decide how to proceed, and when it's redrawn it can redraw using that model, again.  There's no "what *picture* did I click on?"  The logic is closer to the logic of tic-tac-toe.  If you've never done this before, study [TileView](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Snake/src/com/example/android/snake/TileView.html) from the Snake SDK sample.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with this because each item in your gridview is ImageView

```
@Override
public ImageView getItem(int position) {
   return mThumbIds[position];
}
```

and using that method to get the right position of item

```
gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            parent.getItemAtPosition(position).setImageResource(R.drawable.x);
        }
    });
```